# How to run appref-ms (clickOnce) apps via powershell

Tags: powershell, clickonce

I am trying to create a PS script that would read an xml file (server name list) & then run click once app on each of these servers. In my case ,Power shell script execution will be scheduled via Task scheduler.

Now the problem is : I can't find a way to run click once app via Power shell script

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use Start-Process?

Answer (score 1):

I run app ref files by running it through the explorer so an example would be

$fileLocation="C:\temp\program.appref-ms"

explorer.exe $fileLocation

Comment: running in remote for several machines ?

Answer (score 1):

This article documents a process to getting the file path to run the ClickOnce app

https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/

If you can translate this C#/NET code into PowerShell, it should work

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs));
sb.Append("\\Nightbird");                       //ClickOnce Publisher name (eg Nightbird)
sb.Append("\\TestRunningWithArgs.appref-ms ");  //ClickOnce Product name (eg TestRunningWithArgs)
string shortcutPath = sb.ToString();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(shortcutPath, argsToPass);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a ClickOnce application by doing a start process on iexplore.exe and passing it the URL to the ClickOnce deployment. Can you do that in PowerShell? If so, then it should work.

Comment: the URL to the ClickOnce deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
PowerShell "& Start-Process 'file://PATH_OF_YOUR.appref-ms'